# How to simplify the use of pivot in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Age Sex Score
18  M   25
20  F   30
19  M   22
18  M   30
20  F   27
18  M   28
```

I want to get the following:

```
Age Sex Score0 Score1 Score2
18  M   25     30     28
20  F   30     27     -1
19  M   22     -1     -1
```

My steps are:

```
def func(x):
    x['score'] = ['Score' + str(i) for i in range(len(x))]
    return x

df['key'] = df['Sex']  + df['Age'].astype(str)
dg = df.groupby(['Age', 'Sex']).apply(func)
dh =dg.pivot(index='key', columns = 'score', values = 'Score').reset_index().fillna(-1)

score  key  Score0  Score1  Score2
0      F20    30.0    27.0    -1.0
1      M18    25.0    30.0    28.0
2      M19    22.0    -1.0    -1.0
```

Are there any simpler methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
df.groupby(['Age', 'Sex']).Score.apply(
    lambda grp: grp.reset_index(drop=True))\
    .unstack().fillna(-1, downcast='infer').add_prefix('Score')
```

Comment: Thank you, Valdi_Bo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_table` on two columns with `assign`:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby(['Age','Sex']).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot_table(index=['Age','Sex'], columns='col',values='Score', fill_value=-1)
   .add_prefix('Score')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col  Age Sex  Score1  Score2  Score3
0     18   M      25      30      28
1     19   M      22      -1      -1
2     20   F      30      27      -1
```

Comment: wrote pretty much exactly the same answer, except I added the prefix in with the assign which would probably cause more overhead

Comment: Thank you, Quang Hoang.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index([(df['Sex']+df['Age'].astype(str)).rename('key'), 
              'Score'+df.groupby(['Sex','Age']).cumcount().astype(str)])['Score']\
  .unstack(fill_value=-1).reset_index()
   key  Score0  Score1  Score2
0  F20      30      27      -1
1  M18      25      30      28
2  M19      22      -1      -1
```